# how to unregister multiple sensors android

Tags: java, android, sensors

I registered 3 sensors to my sensor manager:

```
if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) !=null ){
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) !=null ){
        gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,gyroscope,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) !=null ){
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,magnetometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
```

and my onResume method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}
```

so when I unregister the sensor manager, should I unregister 3 times, or just once? Currently I use this:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register the listeners you declarare a `SensorListener` (in this case I guess is your activity that `implements SensorEventListener`):

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this,accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
//                             ↑  here
```

So use only once [`unregisterListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#unregisterListener(android.hardware.SensorListener)) because you don't unregister individual sensors, you unregister `SensorListener` as you can see in method signature:

> public void unregisterListener (SensorListener listener)

**UPDATE:**
if you need to disconnect an individual sensor just use the overloaded version of `unregisterListener`

> public void unregisterListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor)